# Need to allow more then 2 Remote Desktop connections at a time

Tags: remote-desktop

Title explains it, I have a m5d.metal aws server running Windows Server 2019 (Datacenter) and I need to allow more then 2 users at a time to be connected. We need around 5 people on their own user (administrator) accounts to be connected to the server, but as of now we can only have 2 without getting the dialog asking to boot one off. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What you want requires additional licenses from Microsoft

Comment: I believe either AWS gives them for free or I can get a trial, but if not I’ll buy it anyways